# R: import and merge only specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr, readr

I have a list of CSV URLs from the net and have merged them to a vector.
Now, I want to read this list with `read_csv`.

Example:

```
files <- c("csv_link1.csv",
             "csv_link2.csv",
             "csv_link3.csv",
              and so on....) 
data <- map_dfr(files, read_csv)
```

This is no problem. The Problem is that in the CSV files there are columns that are filled with different values. So, for example, in CSV1 there is column "V1", which is filled with double and in CSV the same column is "V1", filled with characters. Merging the CSVs does not work because they are different data types.

In my case, I think there are two possibilities to solve this.

1. I only import certain columns, so I say `read_csv` only reads column (V2 and V3) but not V1

Or

2. I merge the columns to the same data type with `col_types`

I have tried both, but failed because of the correct syntax.

I tried something like

```
data <- map_dfr(files, read_csv(cols_only(the col names)))
```

But, this don't work.

How can I import and merge only specific columns?

Concrete Example in my case:

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)
library(purrr)


files <- c("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1819/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1112/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1011/EC.csv")


data <- map_dfr(files, read_csv)

Error: Can't combine `BbAH` <character> and `BbAH` <double>.
```

So i the column `BbAH` has different data types. But i dont need this column.
It would be cool if i can chose the columns which would be merged befor the merge run into an error because of this different data type problem.

Comment: You can try creating a dictionary of datatypes for each column such that after a csv is read, the columns are converted to the appropriate data type based on the dictionary. Then you can merge the dataframes.

Comment: Hi @pontilicious, welcome to StackOveflow!  To get more specific feedback, it would probably be good to also include some of your data. So maybe import the first two files as their own dataframes and then include the results of dput(head(your_datafram_name_here,10)) to show the first ten rows of your data? You can paste that into questions using the "edit" option on the bottom left horizontal menu just under your question.

Comment: @Russ Thomas, thanks for your answer. i updated my question. Hope its okay for reproduction. Greetings :)

Comment: Thanks @pontilicious.  So you mentioned you don't need the ```BbAH``` column. Can you specifiy which columns you do need?

Comment: @Russ 
i only need the columns `(Date,Time,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only needs those seven variables, you can read in those specific variables using `fread` to avoid the issue with the  `BbAH` variable.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

files <- c("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1819/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1112/EC.csv",
           "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1011/EC.csv")

# Identify columns you need
myColumns = c("Date","Time","HomeTeam","AwayTeam","FTHG","FTAG","FTR")

# Modified function found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51348578/8535855
# takes a filename and a vector of columns as input
fread_allfiles <- function(file, columns){
  x <- fread(file, select = columns) %>% 
    select(everything())   # 
  return(x)
}

df_all <- files %>% 
  map_df(~ fread_allfiles(.,myColumns))

head(df_all)
```

which produces the following format:

> ```
>          Date  Time     HomeTeam       AwayTeam FTHG FTAG FTR
> 1: 03/08/2019 12:30    Stockport     Maidenhead    0    1   A
> 2: 03/08/2019 15:00    Aldershot          Fylde    1    2   A
> 3: 03/08/2019 15:00       Barnet         Yeovil    1    0   H
> 4: 03/08/2019 15:00 Chesterfield Dover Athletic    1    2   A
> 5: 03/08/2019 15:00      Chorley        Bromley    0    0   D
> 6: 03/08/2019 15:00  Dag and Red         Woking    0    2   A
> ```

You can then reformat the `Date` and `Time` columns if needed. It looks like on the first file has any values for `Time`? So the rest are filled in as `NA`

```
> str(df_all)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5429 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Date    : chr  "03/08/2019" "03/08/2019" "03/08/2019" "03/08/2019" ...
 $ Time    : chr  "12:30" "15:00" "15:00" "15:00" ...
 $ HomeTeam: chr  "Stockport" "Aldershot" "Barnet" "Chesterfield" ...
 $ AwayTeam: chr  "Maidenhead" "Fylde" "Yeovil" "Dover Athletic" ...
 $ FTHG    : int  0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ FTAG    : int  1 2 0 2 0 2 0 4 2 3 ...
 $ FTR     : chr  "A" "A" "H" "A" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `select` the columns that you need after reading the csvs and combine them using `map_df`.

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- map_df(files, ~read_csv(.x) %>% select(Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR))
```

Comment: tryed this too but the problem is that `read_csv` runs into an error because he cant combine `Season` <double> and `Season` <character>. After this error the `select` command will aborted

Comment: @pontilicious It doesn't give me any error for the files that you have shared. If you other files and there is type mismatch you can convert all of them to characters. Try `result <- map_df(files, ~read_csv(.x) %>% select(Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR) %>% mutate_all(as.character))`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)

rbindlist(lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = "character"))
```

This imports *all* columns as `character`, so you'd need to convert them after the merge to be whatever you initially intended.

Comment: then there is an error `Error: Unknown shortcut: h`