# How to load files with same prefix from different folders into one dataframe in R?

Tags: r, read-data

So I have files that are in the same format with the same prefix "01_qc-..." and these files are also in different folders all labeled "Data...".

How do I read in all of the files simply into one dataframe in R?

Comment: `list.files()` has a `recursive` argument which if set to `TRUE` searches subdirectories.  Set the pattern to `"^01_qc-"`  and `full.names` to `TRUE` to find files with that format and return their complete path.  You can then apply a function such as `read.table` to that list and `rbind` the results into a single dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your input @PaulStaffordAllen, since these datasets are very large, is there a way in `lapply()` to only select certain columns from the datasets while reading in the data?

Comment: @starski, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63867118/18289387) answer uses `map_df` and not `lapply`, but maybe it would be of use.

Comment: It's probably better to preselect the columns when reading the data files in - can you give example formats and column specifications?

Comment: I actually used `fread` in `lapply` and then `rbindlist` and from there I selected the columns I needed, that did the trick